# HIGH_RISK_COUNTRY_CODES ignored for HTTP/2 requests in CRS 3.3.0

Tags: apache2, mod-security

I am using mod_security with CRS 3.3.0 on top of Apache 2.4. During a recent L7 DDoS attack, I recognized that certain attacks using HTTP/1.* were correctly block with HTTP 403 based on geolookup and having the country code listed in **tx.high_risk_country_codes** of the CRS config. However, a request from the identical IP was not blocked when using HTTP/2 as protocol. Any idea of a configuration setting specific for REQUEST-910-IP-REPUTATION.conf only enabled for protocols HTTP/1.* in the default rule set? For the time being, I restricted allowed protocols to HTTP 1.1 for affected site make mod_security working.

Some examples from access log:

<HOST>:443 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [03/Aug/2022:00:37:49 +0200] "GET /?s **HTTP/1.1" 403** 5636 "https://<HOST>/?s" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36"

<HOST>:443 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [03/Aug/2022:00:43:12 +0200] "GET /?s **HTTP/2.0" 301** 392 "https:///?s" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36"

Thanks in advance!

SCHAPPY

Answer (score 0):

CRS dev-on-duty here. There is no configuration setting specific for REQUEST-910-IP-REPUTATION.conf that is only enabled for protocols HTTP/1.*.
I have no idea why the rule 910100 does not work for HTTP/2.

But do you have the possibility to enable debug logs (better not in production) with [SecDebugLog](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#secdebuglog) and [SecDebugLogLevel](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#secdebugloglevel)? Maybe you'll get more insights this way?

If you can't see and solve the problem with the modsec_debug.log, you can open an issue in the [Core Rule Set GitHub project](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset). We're happy to help!